# Length vertical arrow in commutative diagram

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

Consider the following code for a commutative diagram

```
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=50pt]
A \arrow{d}\arrow{r} & B \arrow[leftarrow]{dl}\\
C
\end{tikzcd}
```

I have been able to make the right arrow from A to B longer by adding the argument [column sep=50pt]. How can I make the vertical arrow from A to C longer?

Comment: Add some appropriate `row sep`? Or replace ` \\\` by ` \\\[2cm]`.

Comment: @marmot Could you please write an answer?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two basic options are:

1. Add an appropriate `row sep`.
2. Add a distance after `\\`, e.g. `\\[1.5cm]`.

These options do not do precisely the same in the sense that the distance specified has different meanings as is illustrated in the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=50pt,row sep=50pt]
A \arrow{d}\arrow{r} & B \arrow[leftarrow]{dl}\\
C
\end{tikzcd}
\qquad\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=50pt]
A \arrow{d}\arrow{r} & B \arrow[leftarrow]{dl}\\[50pt]
C
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The first option might be better to set a universal row separation, the second one if you only want to change one out of several.